# Why is inflation incorrect

Tags: inflation, cpi

I track my expenditure accurately. Over the last 13 years, the rise in my cost of living has been zero. This is for true, like for like tracked expenditure. CPI has risen around 38% in that time. 
My view is that CPI is hopelessly flawed in its methodology. Any other views? Is there anyone else that tracks and find their expenditure matches CPI?

This seriously affects my personal finance (which is why it very much is ON topic...) For example, in order to budget I need to put in a value for inflation. I have, in the past, used the central bank target for this- only to find it does not apply to me (in the same way that CPI does not.) I am searching for why this error occurs, hence this question.

Comment: Is this intended as being specific to one country or a general question about inflation measures worldwide?

Comment: Could you show a source for your 80% figure? Pretty confident that's wrong.  Here's a 10-year chart:  https://data.bls.gov/pdq/SurveyOutputServlet?request_action=wh&graph_name=CU_cpibrief

Comment: Your cost of living has not risen in 13 years ! How is that possible ? Groceries cost more every year. Please explain better.

Comment: Normally the opposite holds true, you track your expenditures and because CPI baskets contain things like consumer electronics (which do get cheaper over time) the CPI value reported is *less* than what you calculate yourself.

Comment: Maybe this needs to be on economics.se.

Comment: @HartCO from asker's other posts, they are in the UK. In which case the appropriate things to look are CPIH (includes housing costs) or CPI (doesn't). From the 'Index' time series [here](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/inflationandpriceindices#timeseries), over the 13 years to Nov 2017, the increase in CPI is 35.8% (CPIH doesn't go back 13 years). Not sure where "around 80%" has come from.

Comment: Yes you are right- since jan 04 CPI is 38% (UK figures). But my personal inflation is 0% +- 2.5% (it jumps around because of uneven spending, but the  trend is clear at zero) Groceries may go up, but LEDs, insulation, better heating controllers, low power tvs etc mean that (my) energy costs go down.

Comment: CPI tracks reductions in consumer prices, but NOT the increase in their utility. B&W tubed tvs are not the same as color smart tvs... It tracks car prices, but not their increased longevity and improved mileage.

Comment: RonJohn, it is not the economics aspect that I am interested in, it is the effect it has on my budgeting. My aim is to translate what is no doubt a useful macro-economic datum into something useful for personal finance use. That it is used for e.g. pay negotiation means that it is believed to apply to individuals. My experience is that it is a poor guide. I would like to know why.

Answer (score 8):

CPI tracks the cost of a fixed bundle of goods, intended to represent the purchases of a 'typical' person. However some things are excluded - mortgage, maybe rent, and some goods with volatile pricing.

If your purchases aren't typical, your expenses won't track the CPI. If your expenses other than CPI goods change, your total cost of living can change completely differently from what the CPI says. If your lifestyle changes then your expenses will also change in a way not corresponding with the CPI.

Comment: It's a disingenuous way of them to say it that way, but I _think_ the OP is saying CPI has _risen_ by 80% (which could be 1.0% pa to 1.8% pa), not _gone to_ 80%. (It's as similarly misleading as the "scare" headlines that so-and-so "_increases your risk of cancer by 50%_" when the risk has gone from say 0.01% to 0.015%).

Comment: No, it was an error on my part. The figure is 38%, and I have corrected the question.

Comment: You are right that it is meant to apply to a 'typical' person. But if the error across the population is great ( and my case is 38% error) should the figure not include, say, 95% error bars? Does anyone do the figures for the spread? Inflation figures hit the news on an monthly basis. Why, if the errors are so great?

Comment: You are 1 person of the 350 million affected. Even if your error is 250% that would not be an indication that there is a problem for all of the other people. You might - and probably do- have very different spending patterns from the typical person.

Comment: @MikeM: at least over here in Germany, the Statistische Bundesamt [Federal Statistical Office] does something even better (IMHO) than constructing confidence intervals: they collect, record and publish not only "the" consumer price index but also the prices of lots of individual items and classes of goods (e.g. https://www.destatis.de/DE/ZahlenFakten/Indikatoren/Konjunkturindikatoren/Preismonitor/Preismonitor.html) - and even provide a web app where you can estimate your personal inflation based on how much of what types of goods you consume ...

Comment: ... (https://www.destatis.de/DE/Service/InteraktiveAnwendungen/InflationsrechnerSVG.svg). They also have an app  that visualizes the different goods and their weights into the CPI (https://service.destatis.de/Voronoi/PreisKaleidoskop.svg) and they publish several conumer price indices for "model households" such as singles/families of 2 and 4, different income categories etc. IMHO you should not blame the Statistical Office if the news pick one (or 12) number from a 200+ page yearly report full of information...

Comment: @Mike M: Because it is not an error for you to be a non-typical person.  It is simply a lifestyle choice.

Comment: The German method seems better, but I am not sure it helps with forecasting inflation. Whilst the past is interesting, the purpose for me is to budget more accurately. As a retired person, I budget for the next 20 years- the plan is to spend (most of) my capital, so I need to factor in inflation. Errors in this have a huge effect over decades...

Comment: CPI is not intended to forecast inflation. It only deals with the past.